# update-initramfs hangs, could relate to update-grub?

Tags: linux, grub, ubuntu-20.04

On my Ubuntu 20.04, all commands that relate to update-grub hangs. If using apt install/remove/upgrade it points to use

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Running that command, will cause following lines to get stuck

```
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-60-generic
```

Running 'ps af' points to update-grub. Have waited more then one hour, nothing happens.

If first started that when apt was removing an old /boot/initrd.img-5.x.xx. Where update-grub was stuck as well.

Any solution how to solve this issue?

```
/etc/default/grup
Consist of one line:
GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=true

sudo update-grub 
Don't print anything and never ends.

Anthing that has to apt to do, cause to write out that i need to re-configure with the command "dpkg --configure -a".

...
apt policy grub
grub:
  Installerad: 0.97-29ubuntu68
  Kandidat:    0.97-29ubuntu68
...

ps af
.......
3122456 pts/8    Ss     0:00      \_ sudo su
3122457 pts/8    S      0:00          \_ su
3122462 pts/8    S      0:00              \_ bash
1417255 pts/8    T      0:00                  \_ apt autoremove
1423444 pts/9    Ss+    0:00                  |   \_ /usr/bin/dpkg --status-fd 60 --no-triggers --force-depends --abort-after=1 --remove linux-image-5.8.0-63-generic:amd64
1423609 pts/9    S+     0:00                  |       \_ /bin/sh /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-5.8.0-63-generic.postrm remove
1423636 pts/9    S+     0:00                  |           \_ run-parts --report --exit-on-error --arg=5.8.0-63-generic --arg=/boot/vmlinuz-5.8.0-63-generic /etc/kernel/postrm.d
1423645 pts/9    S+     0:37                  |               \_ /bin/sh /usr/sbin/update-grub
```

Comment: We need some clarity here, please. Your initial text reads as gibberish. Please [edit] the question and describe what you're trying to do (and why) and post the full error messages.

Comment: So haven't you done `dpkg --configure -a` yet? What does it say?

Comment: `delete old img` - HOW?

Comment: `$ dpkg --list | grep 5.8.0-63-generic` `ii` at the beginning of the line => installed. Now note that you cannot remove the running kernel version, the version listed by `uname -a`